# How to stop handler inside BroadcastReceiver after phone call is answered or canceled?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, handler, flashlight, blink

I'm trying to create simple Android application that simulate camera flashlight blink while phone call is received. If the user answer or cancel the call, I want to stop the flashlight blink. I'm using Handler and Runnable to simulate blinking, but the problem is that I can't stop the handler after user answer or cancel the call. My source code:

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    private static Camera cam = null;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //device is ringing
        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
        {
            if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) 
            {
                startFlashBlink();
            }
        }
        //call was answered or canceled
        else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE) 
            || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
        {
            stopFlashBlink();
        }
    }

    //for simulating flash blink
    Runnable flashBlinkRunnable = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() 
        {   
            cam = Camera.open();
            Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            cam.setParameters(p);
            cam.startPreview();
            cam.stopPreview();
            cam.release();
            cam = null;
            handler.post(flashBlinkRunnable);
        }       
    };

    //start flash blink light
    public void startFlashBlink()
    {
        flashBlinkRunnable.run();
    }

    //stop flash blink light
    public void stopFlashBlink()
    {
        handler.removeCallbacks(flashBlinkRunnable);
        if (cam != null)
        {
            cam.stopPreview();
            cam.release();
            cam = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't work like this. There is serious flaw in your code. The problem is that you can't use `BroadcastReceiver` this way. From the documentation of `BroadcastReceiver`:

> A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call
>   to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this
>   function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer
>   active.

Also note this from the app fundamentals in the docs:

> More commonly, though, a broadcast receiver is just a "gateway" to
>   other components and is intended to do a very minimal amount of work.
>   For instance, it might initiate a service to perform some work based
>   on the event.

So your broadcast receiver ought to start a service and tell it to start or stop flash blinking instead of doing it in the broadcast receiver itself.

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast receivers are a way to tell the OS that has a intention of to do something, than the OS find a app to resolve that intent.
In your case, all of your code is in broadcast receiver. Try to create a service to resolve your problem instead try to resolve in your broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved with a Service.

```
public class FlashBlinkService extends Service 
{
    private static Camera cam = null;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        startFlashBlink();      
    }

    //for simulating flash blink
    Runnable flashBlinkRunnable = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() 
        {   
            cam = Camera.open();
            Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            cam.setParameters(p);
            cam.startPreview();
            cam.stopPreview();
            cam.release();
            cam = null;
            handler.post(flashBlinkRunnable);
        }       
    };

    //start flash blink light
    public void startFlashBlink()
    {
        flashBlinkRunnable.run();
    }

    //stop flash blink light
    public void stopFlashBlink()
    {
        handler.removeCallbacks(flashBlinkRunnable);
        stopCamera(cam);
    }

    //stop camera
    private void stopCamera(Camera cam)
    {
        if (cam != null)
        {
            cam.stopPreview();
            cam.release();
            cam = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        handler.removeCallbacks(flashBlinkRunnable);
        stopCamera(cam);
    }
}


public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //device is ringing
        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
        {
            if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) 
            {
                startFlashBlinkService(context);
            }
        }
        //call was answered or canceled
        else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE) 
                || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
        {
            stopFlashBlinkService(context);
        }
    }

    //start flash blink light
    public void startFlashBlinkService(Context context)
    {
        if (!isBlinkServiceRunning(context))
        {
            Intent iService = new Intent(context, FlashBlinkService.class);
            context.startService(iService);
        }
    }

    //stop flash blink light
    public void stopFlashBlinkService(Context context)
    {
        if (isBlinkServiceRunning(context))
        {
            Intent iService = new Intent(context, FlashBlinkService.class);
            context.stopService(iService);
        }
    }


    //check if the blink service is running
    public boolean isBlinkServiceRunning(Context context)
    {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
        {
            if ("path.to.package.FlashBlinkService".equals(service.service.getClassName()))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

(: